# MS-Access using Dlookup to pull results from query into textbox on form

Tags: ms-access, expression, frm

I am very new to access and I am using the Dlookup function to pull the results from a query into a text box to appear on a form. 
I have the following expression in the Data Control Source field for the text box and it is pulling in the very first result from the query. 
    =DLookUp("SumOfSales","qTtlSalesbyComp","Company = Company")

I need it to act as a vlookup and match the Company in the query to the Company in the Company text box and pull the SumofSales that corresponds. Any hep would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this a single form or continuous form? If the latter, it would be better to  JOIN its recordsource with `qTtlSalesbyComp` instead of using DLookup.

Answer (score 0):

If `Company` is text:

```
=DLookUp("SumOfSales","qTtlSalesbyComp","Company = '" & Company & "'")
```

If it is numerical:

```
=DLookUp("SumOfSales","qTtlSalesbyComp","Company = " & Company )
```

Comment: #Type! on the form

Comment: I would have to know the exact type of all the field involved to troubleshoot that. I assume the qTtlSalesbyComp itself does work and has a SumOfSales field. In that case most likely whatever you type for `Company` does not match a result on your query. try this: `=Nz(DLookup([add your dlookup code]),"No Match")`

Answer (score 0):

I just could not seem to get the Dlookup to work. I ended up using subforms to pull in the query results. I believe this ended up being a much cleaner way of executing what I wanted.